# How to check cookies consent status if no retrieval is allowed by EU law?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I read it from https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/ that in EU, you must show cookies consent before storing and retrieving any cookies.

Then how can I check if the user previously agreed with the consent? Normally I would set a cookie like

> alreadyConsented

or something, but it would violate the rule of no retrieval before consent.

I do not want to show the cookies consent every time the same user visited the site. And my page is entirely client-sided.

**Edit**: Update the link and quote

> The Cookie Law is a piece of privacy legislation that requires
>   websites to get consent from visitors to store or retrieve any
>   information on a computer, smartphone or tablet.

Comment: "I read it from https://www.cookielaw.org/ that in EU, you must show cookies consent before storing and retrieving any cookies" — Can you provide a more specific link and a quote? Because cookies simply don't work like that. Cookies are not "retrieved" they are sent, automatically, by the browser to the server if they are set.

Comment: Are you sure that ALL cookies fall under this directive?

Comment: @Quentin : I updated the link and the quote

Answer (score 2):

Show the cookie consent box once if user allows (clicks on allow), set the cookies.

Also set a cookie like **consent-allowed = true**.

Next time when the page is loaded check for the consent-allowed cookie, if it is set that means that the user has allowed else show the consent.

Comment: but it means that I have to check/retrieve the consent-allowed first, which the point I do not know if user have accepted the consent or not.

Comment: You are not actually not setting a cookie before the user gives consent. You are simply checking for the cookie. If it exists you know that the user agreed and if not then show the consent prompt